# Encoding Problem in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

Below is my code..

```
NSString *strResponce = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JsonData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

here string has some data.

```
[JsonData release];
NSError *error;
SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

ArrayWebContent=[json objectWithString:strResponce error:&error];
```

But array is null.

any suggestion....

Comment: I also used NSUTF8stringEncoding. but its not working. array has no content....

Comment: Print your string after you create it.

Comment: it's json data so the content is in json format.

Comment: do this things to localize the problem  first check  the json object see if it's initialized,then check to see if the strResponce isn't empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your json data first  put the content of the string strResponce in to the url

[Checking json data are proper for parsing](http://braincast.nl/samples/jsoneditor/)

if it gonna generate the parse error than you should check the content of the ws  as it may content special charactor for which iphone can not support parsing

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try with below functions.

```
- (id) objectWithUrl:(NSURL *)url
{

    SBJSON *jsonParser = [SBJSON new];
    NSString *jsonString = [self stringWithUrl:url];

    // Parse the JSON into an Object
    return [jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString error:NULL];
}

- (NSString *)stringWithUrl:(NSURL *)url
{

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                            timeoutInterval:30];
    // Fetch the JSON response
    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    // Make synchronous request
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                    returningResponse:&response
                                                error:&error];

    // Construct a String around the Data from the response
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Let me know for any difficulty.